# Is my hash table code correct?

Tags: java, hashtable

I was learning hash table with open addressing using linear probing in Java language.
Can somebody check my following code implementation please:

```
public class HashTableOpenAddressing {    
private int table_size = 3;    
private HashTableNode[] hash_table = new HashTableNode[table_size];   
class HashTableNode{
    public int key;
    public int value;        
    HashTableNode(int key, int value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}   

HashTableOpenAddressing(){
    for(int i = 0; i < table_size; i++){
        hash_table[i] = null;
    }

}

public void insert(int key, int value){        
    int hash_code = hash_code(key);        
    if(hash_code == 0){
        System.out.println("The hash table is full!!!"); 
        return;
    } 
    hash_table[hash_code] = new HashTableNode(key, value);        
    return;        
}       

public int hash_code(int key) {
    return linear_probing(key);
}


public int linear_probing(int key) {

    for(int i = 0; i< table_size; i++) {
        // if we get next empty slot to insert new node then return the new hash code
        if(hash_table[((key+i) % table_size)] == null) {
            return ((key+i) % table_size);
        }           
    }
    return 0;       
}

public void print_hash_table() {

    for(int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
        if(hash_table[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("key: ____"+"  value:____ ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("key: "+hash_table[i].key+"  value: "+hash_table[i].value);
        }
    }
    return;
}    
}
```

And here is the Test code:

```
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        HashTableOpenAddressing ht = new HashTableOpenAddressing();
        ht.insert(10, 100);
        ht.insert(10, 1000);
        ht.insert(11, 101);         
        ht.print_hash_table();          
    }
}
```

On the test code, i tried to insert 3 key-vlue nodes in the hash table.
If the code is correct then why the 3rd item is not inserted in the hash table?
please help me to explain
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be your choice of using a return value of `0` from `linear_probing` as an error indicator, while that can be a valid hash code. Remember that array indices are zero-based in Java.

You can solve the problem by changing your error code return value to `-1`, and then changing `insert` to check for the hash code being less than 0. With this simple change, your code appears to work correctly for me.

```
public void insert(int key, int value) {
    int hash_code = hash_code(key);
    if (hash_code < 0) {
        System.out.println("The hash table is full!!!");
        return;
    }
    hash_table[hash_code] = new HashTableNode(key, value);
    return;
}

public int linear_probing(int key) {

    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
        // if we get next empty slot to insert new node then return the new hash code
        if (hash_table[((key + i) % table_size)] == null) {
            return ((key + i) % table_size);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I also modified the test to attempt to add one more value, which fails appropriately.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashTableOpenAddressing ht = new HashTableOpenAddressing();
    ht.insert(10, 100);
    ht.insert(10, 1000);
    ht.insert(11, 101);
    ht.insert(11, 1001);
    ht.print_hash_table();
}
```

Output:

```
The hash table is full!!!
key: 11  value: 101
key: 10  value: 100
key: 10  value: 1000
```